# Does pushing a git tag to origin copy files?

Tags: git, tags

Following the instructions [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) I created a local annotated tag and then pushed it to a remote server via

```
git push origin [tagname]
```

I was surprised to see large file size in the output:

```
$ git push origin v1.5
Counting objects: 50, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 204.56 MiB, done.
Total 44 (delta 18), reused 8 (delta 1)
To git@github.com:schacon/simplegit.git
* [new tag]         v1.5 -> v1.5
```

Did I just create a copy of everything in the repository? That is, will every tag I create take ~204 MB on the server?

Answer (score 1):

A tag is only a file pointing to a specifig commit. What was 204MB were the files in the repository. Your push size depends on the size of the files changed since the last push.

So by pushing you created a complete copy of everything in the repository that was not in the remote repository before. By creating a tag you created a file containing the pointer to one commit and some metadata (i.e. a pretty small file).

If you are interested in more details of how this internaly works in git: file storage is [Chapter 9.2](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of the documentation (your 200+MB) and the way they are referenced is [Chapter 9.3](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References) (what happens when you create a tag)

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't create a copy of your whole repository.

As @Trudbert said:

> A tag is only a file pointing to a specific commit what was 204MB was the rest of the repository. So your push size depends on the size of the changes since the last push.

A tag is only a pointer to the commit. If the commit is already in the server, then it should only a few kilobytes big. If not, the commit needs to be pushed also, and that's what makes your push a big file size depending on the size of the commits.